# Create multi level sub folder structure in PHP

Tags: php, filesystems, directory

I'm trying to create a folder structure which has multi level sub folders. For example, I want to create a folder structure like 'Fruits/Edible/Seedless'. I tried it with mkdir($path) but it could not done. I tried with single level folder, its created. Help me to create this subfolder structure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the recursive flag for [mkdir](http://php.net/mkdir)($path, $chmod, $recursive)

```
<?php
mkdir($path, 0, true);
?>
```

From php.net=
recursive
Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the pathname. Defaults to FALSE.

Comment: Using 0777 (which is the default) instead of 0 will give it the widest possible access.

Answer (score 6):

```
bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )
```

See specifically: `bool $recursive = false`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: Thank you @Jared Farrish for your reply with explanation with link.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Linux `exec` command in the following way to achieve this,

```
<?php 
  exec("mkdir -p ".$path);
?>
```

`-p` won't throw any error if directory exists, otherwise it will create the directory along with the parent directories.