# Save file (can be jpg,css,js...) with cURL to my server and keep directory structure

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

To make it simple:

1. I have an image file ex: https://www.example.com/a/b/c/image.jpg
2. I want to use curl to download and save the image on my server but I want to keep the directory structure, so I want to save the file on my server to a/b/c/image.jpg , so the directories must also be created if they do not exist already
3. If the file already exist to not download

Hope someone with more experience can help because I have tried 2 days on this an nothing.

For now I only have the CURL function that is working good:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $urltoget );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    $tempsavefile = curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly your problem with the next steps was then. How to create directories via PHP should be easy enough to research, and how to check if a specific file already exists as well. So explain what your specific problem was/is.

Comment: the step to parse the url to get only the directories and create them if they do not exist

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485072/create-multi-level-sub-folder-structure-in-php

Comment: Thank you, this is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485072/create-multi-level-sub-folder-structure-in-php I will try to fix the script now. THANKS!